# Adding calculated field from VBA in an Excel 2011 macro to a pivot table in an Excel 2003 book

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2003, excel-2011, vba

I have a macro running in an Excel 2011 workbook that is manipulating a pivot table in an Excel 2003 book. So far I haven't add issues with adding or hiding fields.

I'm trying to add a calculated field (as here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834479(v=office.14).aspx) and it is not working.

```
ws.PivotTables("RetailerMgmt").CalculatedFields.Add "ASP", " = TYDSMTD/TYUSMTD", FALSE
```

Gets me Error 450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

When I recorded the same task, the result was:

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro "(""RetailerMgmt"",1,""ASP"",""=TYDSMTD/TYUSMTD"",TRUE)"
```

Which was recorded and saved in the 2003 file, so I'm sure it's some Excel 2003 business (doesn't work when run from 2011).

So, is there any way to add a calculated field to a pivot table in a 2003 workbook from a macro being run in a 2011 workbook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding it easier to just save my source data book as an .xlsx file within the macro, then dealing with it from there.